# Laravel 5.6 framework and unable to make connection to mssql server using odbc_connect()

Tags: php, sql-server, laravel

Trying the standard Laravel database config sqlsrv template failing, I have moved to a direct PHP odbc_connect() approach to attempt a connection to my work SQL Server via Laravel 5.6.

I am building a dashboard at work behind a corporate firewall and another developer has successfully created a connection using the following:

```
$resource = odbc_connect('Driver={ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server};Server=xxxxxxxxxx;Trusted_Connection=yes;ApplicationIntent=ReadOnly', null, null)
```

odbc_connect() above is setup to use the current Network AD Windows Authentication I am signed into, however, I receive the following ErrorException from Laravel:

```
odbc_connect(): SQL error: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server]Login timeout expired, SQL state S1T00 in SQLConnect
```

phpinfo:

- ODBC Library: unixODBC
- PDO Drivers: mysql, odbc, sqlite, sqlsrv
- PDO_ODBC: Enabled, strict matching
- PHP Version 7.1.10

I can successfully connect SQL Server GUI clients (RazorSQL and Navicat) Which both are using Windows Authentication methods. Please note, I am running a MAC OSX Sierra.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `Login timeout expired` seems consuming more time to connect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server located in the obdcinst.ini file linked to a file that didn't recognise windows auth. The solution was to brew install freetds with unixodbc which created a lib that recognised authentication. I then swapped the lib over. Upon authentication I did add a username and password however the username having a double backslash, therefore, the username would be YOURDOMAIN\username. For some reason Laravel will see this and treat it as a domain login whilst removing a backslash, the request is sent to the server and then allowing myself to login successfully to perform the queries as expected.

Hope this helps anyone who is in this same situation.